# Getting data from elasticsearch when field is undefined or missing from object

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get data from elastic search by querying some field which indicates if the object was already handled. let's call it 'isHandled".

There are some objects that indexed without this field.
Is there any way to get the data that "isHandled" is just not "true" (false or even missing)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `exists` query to achieve that. This query will return you all documents where `isHandled` is either false or not existing.

```
{

  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "isHandled": "false"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "isHandled"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```